# Are uppercase URLs in QR codes universally usable?

Tags: qr-code

I am creating a QR code for this website: https://hour.gg

If using the naive way with the text "https://hour.gg" and medium error correction this requires a version 2 code (25x25 modules).

But using the text "HTTPS://HOUR.GG" fits into a version 1 code (21x21 modules).

(Typically you will prefer a lower version because it is easier to scan. (Version 1 might be the exception because v2 has the extra tracking corner.))

---

The uppercase version scans correctly on iPhone.

Are uppercase URLs (including schemes) a recognized standard and do they work universally (99%+ of modern devices that humans actually have)?

Comment: the `HTTPS://` part and the HOSTNAME will be fine as uppercase.  If there's a path or query param after the hostname, that's technically case sensitive, but it tends to work.  Case in point: HTTPS://STACKOVERFLOW.COM/QUESTIONS/76394417/ARE-UPPERCASE-URLS-IN-QR-CODES-UNIVERSALLY-USABLE